# Sprintboot Runtime error : Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.entity.Department

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

Departmentclass:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Department {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private long departmentid;
private String departmentName;
private String departmentAddress;
private String departmentcode;
}
```

Department Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface DepartmentRepository extends JpaRepository<Department, Long> {

Department findByDepartmentId(long departmentid);
}
```

Department service:
@Service
@Slf4j
public class DepartmentService {

```
@Autowired
private DepartmentRepository departmentrepository;

public Department saveDepartment(Department department) {
    
    log.info("Inside savedepartment method of deparment service");
    return departmentrepository.save(department);
}

public Department finddepaartmentbyid(long departmentid) {
log.info("inside finddepartmentbyid mehtod of departmentservice");
return departmentrepository.findByDepartmentId(departmentid);
}
}
```

Department controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/departments")
@Slf4j
public class DepartmentController {

@Autowired
private DepartmentService departmentservice;

@PostMapping("/")
public Department saveDepartment(@RequestBody Department department)
{
    log.info("Inside savedepatment method of department controller");
    return departmentservice.saveDepartment(department);
}

@GetMapping("{id}")
public Department finddepartmentbyid(@PathVariable long departmentid)
{
    log.info("inside finddepartmentbyid mehtod of department controller");
    return departmentservice.finddepaartmentbyid(departmentid);
}
}
```

I am getting runtime error as Failed to create query for method public abstract com.example.demo.entity.Department com.example.demo.repository.DepartmentRepository.findByDepartmentId(long)! No property departmentId found for type Department! Did you mean 'departmentid'?

Comment: Looks like `departmentid` is not camel case like it should be?

Comment: Note that you don't need to define that method _at all_ if it's the native `@Id` property; you can just use `find`/`findOne` (depending on your version of Spring Data).

Answer (score 1):

You need to be cautious how you name the repository methods. In your repository code, you say `Department findByDepartmentId(long departmentid);`. So Spring is trying to make a search on the variable `departmentId`(Notice how camel casing matters here). Unfortunately, your entity class for the repository `DepartmentRepository` which is `Department` does not have any field by name `departmentId` and rather it has `departmentid`.

Here are 2 solutions:

1. Rename repository method to `Department findByDepartmentid(long departmentid);`: **THIS IS NOT RECOMMENDED**.
2. Change the `departmentid` in `Department` entity class to `departmentId`:
   **RECOMMENDED AND BEST PRACTICE**

You can find more details on naming repository methods [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods)

Comment: @Naren can you please accept the answer if it solved your problem?